# Initializing a Wrapped Class In Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance

I'm working on some updates to a machine learning project that I found here: https://github.com/davidADSP/SIMPLE

In the original code, the train class looks up the 'environment' for the game it is playing and initializes it with:

```
  logger.info('\nSetting up the selfplay training environment opponents...')
  base_env = get_environment(args.env_name)
  env = selfplay_wrapper(base_env)(opponent_type = args.opponent_type, verbose = args.verbose)
  env.seed(workerseed)
```

selfplay_wrapper is a wrapper function that extends the functionality of the env class like:

```
def selfplay_wrapper(env):
    class SelfPlayEnv(env):
        # wrapper over the normal single player env, but loads the best self play model
        def __init__(self, opponent_type, verbose):
            super(SelfPlayEnv, self).__init__(verbose)
            self.opponent_type = opponent_type
            self.opponent_models = load_all_models(self)
            self.best_model_name = get_best_model_name(self.name)

        def reset(self):
            super(SelfPlayEnv, self).reset()
            self.setup_opponents()

            if self.current_player_num != self.agent_player_num:   
                self.continue_game()

            return self.observation

    return SelfPlayEnv
```

The environment class extends gym.env and looks like this:

```
class SushiGoEnv(gym.Env):
    metadata = {'render.modes': ['human']}

    def __init__(self, verbose = False, manual = False):
        super(SushiGoEnv, self).__init__()
        self.name = 'sushigo'
        self.manual = manual
        self.turns_taken = 0
        self.n_players = 3

    def reset(self):
        self.round = 0
        self.deck = Deck(self.contents)
        self.discard = Discard()
        self.players = []
        self.action_bank = []
```

As written everything works, but I wanted to add an abstract parent class that defines all the common methods and properties for the environment classes. I created a super class called Environment:

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod
from typing import Any
from gym import Env

class Environment(Env, metaclass=ABCMeta):
    current_player_num: int

    def __init__(self, n_players, turns_taken, device='cpu'):
        super(Environment, self).__init__()
        self.device = device
        self.n_players = n_players
        self.turns_taken = turns_taken

    @abstractmethod
    def reset(self):
        pass
```

and modified the SushiGoEnv class to extend it:

```
class SushiGoEnv(Environment):
    metadata = {'render.modes': ['human']}
    def __init__(self, verbose = False, manual = False):
        super(SushiGoEnv, self).__init__(n_players=3, device='cuda', turns_taken=0)
        self.name = 'sushigo'
        self.manual = manual
```

Everything looks fine at first glance, but when I try to run it I get a run-time error:

```
  File "C:\Users\bucpa\Documents\workspace\SIMPLE\app\train.py", line 66, in main
    env = selfplay_wrapper(base_env)(opponent_type = args.opponent_type, verbose = args.verbose)
  File "C:\Users\bucpa\Documents\workspace\SIMPLE\app\utils\selfplay.py", line 14, in selfplay_wrapper
    class SelfPlayEnv(env):
TypeError: SushiGoEnv.__init__() takes from 1 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong here. Obviously the environment class is not getting the expected number of arguments, but I don't know why. Is there a better way to implement a  wrapper like this?

Comment: I think your code example is missing some lines.  For instance, the `selfplay_wrapper()` function doesn't return anything as written. Is it supposed to return the SelfPlayEnv class? Right now your example code does not produce a minimally reproducible example. I'd recommend abstracting away all of the ML-specific code and just create an example with a wrapped class and the desired inheritance structure

Comment: `selfplay_wrapper` is not a class, it is a function, and its not clear to me what function it performs.  Why not just define `SelfPlayEnv` at the global level?

Comment: My mistake. I missed the return statement when I was copy/pasting. It should be correct now.

Comment: @TimRoberts I'm not the original author of the code, but as best I can determine, SelfPlayEnv is adding/overriding functionality from the env class. Since we don't know what class env will be at compile time, it can't do normal inheritance. If there is a better way to do this, let me know.

Comment: you should provide a [mcve]

Comment: Hmm.  Doesn't `get_environment` always return the same class of thing?  I suppose that's really irrelevant to your question.